# Invalid image format after sending image from Server to client using socket in android

Tags: android, image, sockets

I am trying to send image from server socket to client socket so i am getting correct image path and converting into bytes and from client side i am receiving data also but after saving to storage its not opening the file , it showing that invalid image.

> Image size is correct but its dimension is -1 X -1

Server side code onActivityResult i am getting the image URI

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();
        String path = uri.getPath();
        Log.e(TAG, path);


        if (mBoundService != null) {
            mSOcket = mBoundService.getSocket();
            mSocketArraylist = mBoundService.getSocketArrayList();
            if (mSocketArraylist != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < mSocketArraylist.size(); i++) {
                    Socket mSocket = mSocketArraylist.get(i);
                    OutputStream os = null;
                    try {
                        os = mSocket.getOutputStream();
                        ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
                        InputStream is = null;
                        try {
                            is = cr.openInputStream(Uri.parse(uri.toString()));
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                        }


                        copyFile(is, os);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } else {
                Log.e("Socket value", "Socket is null");
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Client side code

```
  if (wifiInfo != null) {
        if (!wifiInfo.isGroupOwner) {
            String host = wifiInfo.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress();

            Socket clientSocket = new Socket();

            OutputStream os = null;

            try {
                clientSocket.bind(null);
                clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
                clientSocket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(host, port)), SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

                os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);


                InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String data = br.readLine();

                Log.e(TAG, data + "");


                final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + ClientService.this.getPackageName() + "/wifip2pshared-" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                        + ".jpg");


                File dirs = new File(f.getParent());
                if (!dirs.exists())
                    dirs.mkdirs();
                f.createNewFile();

                String line;
                while (true) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "server: copying files " + f.toString());
                    InputStream inputstream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                    copyFile(inputstream, new FileOutputStream(f));

                    break;
                }

                signalActivity(f.getAbsolutePath());
                Thread.sleep(500000);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());

            }
```

copyFile method implementation is given below

```
public static boolean copyFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream out) {
    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    try {
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        out.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

So any one can help me out in this.

Comment: dont help m out thn because you dont knw the problem and its solution also

Comment: @greenapps what hppn now , So tell me the solution now ..

Comment: This is my way if you dont like so dont react on that and if u knw the solution now i will never use thanks in advance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144345/discussion-between-nikhil-sharma-and-greenapps).

Comment: Yes i have removed it now you tell me what is the problem in that]

Comment: Please dont command me. The server code does not look ok. With the client code it is not possible to receive images.

Comment: First the server. Are you using StrictMode or so? As all internet code should be executed in a thread ar async task.

Comment: actually i am using service for ServerSocket and i have reference of Socket on my activity so on activityResult i am using socket reference and from that reference m sending the data

Comment: Yes that is what i saw. But that can never work as such internet code should be in a thread. For which Android version are you compiling?

Comment: `is = cr.openInputStream(Uri.parse(uri.toString()));`. Dont mess around. `is = cr.openInputStream(data.getData());`

Comment: Yaa i have implemented thread now but the problem is there

Comment: Then first update your code here too.

Comment: The problem is the BufteredReader. It steals data from subsequent reads on the underlying stream. See the duplicate for how to do without this problem.

Comment: Couldnt you wait with that @EJP ... And buffered or not... Reading lines is not a good idea. Dont use readers for images.

Comment: @EJP Thanks its worked for me

Comment: @greenapps Thanks for your help also but u didnt solved my problem ...may be becoz of your way of talking and attitude problem